# Why same VBA excel files but have different compile result?

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, vba

I have two similar file [file01-hasError](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/2012/same%20file%20but%20different%20compile%20result/Error.xlsm) and [file02-noError](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/2012/same%20file%20but%20different%20compile%20result/NoError.xlsm)

I cannot understand what's wrong with them since they both have the same module `request` that defines the same method bbb(); but one results in error while the other doesn't.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NoError` file contains a reference to `Microsoft XML, V6.0`, the `Error` file does not.

Error is then caused by the line `Public xmlHttpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60`

Set it under `\Tools\References...`

Answer (score 1):

`file01` has compile error because it does not reference to `MicrosoftXML`. Open menu `Tools|References`  and find and tick MicrosoftXML6.0, apply it. Error will disapear

Comment: Oh, @ChrisNeilsen answer before me ^^